# Application throws warning message to enable cookies while running through IEDriver with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was automating an angularjs application using selenium webdriver. I am using IEDriver 32 bit version to driver the IE execution. Typically, the scenario is admin user will register a user, this user will click on the registration link mailed to their maid id. Then it will input some required information, automatically it will be navigated to login page where user have to input the username and password and login.
But application warns to enable cookies at this point of time. If we are renavigating to the login page there is no issue.

This issue is not reproducible everytime. 
Is there any way to enable cookies while setting up the IE profile?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways as you can find cookies in the below path 
In Windows 8 for IE10, cookies are saved in the hidden protected OS folders below:

C:\Users(user name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies
you can open IE and then navigate to internet options/privacy/advanced privacy settings.

There you can accept and block cookies.

Comment: This setting I changed to Accept all cookies but still I am facing the issue while running through webdriver. Manually there is no issue.

Comment: To enable cookies try the following command :-                           String command = "REG ADD \"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\ \" /v       1A10 /t REG_DWORD /d 0X1 /f";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);